# ASP.NET 4.5 is not registered after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: asp.net, windows, wcf, iis

I have a WCF web service which was working on Windows 8.1. After upgrading to Windows 10, I noticed that the IIS is not installed anymore. So I installed it along with ASP.NET 4.6 in Windows features. Now, when I open the project in VS2013 it says that ASP.NET 4.5 is not registered. Shouldn't it work with ASP.NET 4.6?

Comment: Registered iis ? aspnet_regiis -i  ..let me knw

Comment: I tried that, it is not applicable in windows 8 and later.

Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.0
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Start installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).
This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it by installing Visual Studio 2013 Service Pack 5 (the latest at that time).

You can download it from here:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-update5-vs.aspx

Make sure to select the right version according to the Visual Studio version you have.

Comment: I can't say, I did not have this problem when moving to VS 2015